# Domain mapping to appspot project

Tags: domain, g-suite, godaddy, google-app-engine

I have setted up domain mapping from courses.reframe.space to my google app (on appspot.com) in cloud console via CNAME record pointed to ghs.googlehosted.com (as Google suggests here - https://goo.gl/rIqjtQ) many days ago, but it still not working. GoDaddy rooted me to Google Support - they think issue is on Google side.

Comment: What did Google Support say?

Comment: I'm Bronze support package user. Can't contact they for technical questions.

Comment: appears working now...

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the correct ghs.googlehosted.com CNAME record for your [courses.reframe.space](http://courses.reframe.space/) domain, yet your domain serves a 404 not found.

I recommend you report this issue in a [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) and provide your Google Cloud project ID for the application that your custom domain is configured for. This way we will be able to take a deeper look at your custom domain configuration to see where the issue is.